# What do you do when you need whole-words search in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Example: I am looking to see if "arg" is a special keyword in Lua. I go to the Lua reference manual at http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html. I search for "arg". I find hundreds of occurrences of the word "argument(s)" or "vararg".

Any ideas? I know Firefox won't implement whole words as a core feature (something about cluttering up the ui... argh...), and I couldn't find a good addon that implemented this well.

Comment: This is still a problem after all these years. Did you find a good solution?

Comment: @DCShannon I'm afraid not, no. The work happening in [Bug 269442](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=269442#c94) briefly raised my hopes, but nothing usable yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually search for something like this:

```
<space>arg<space>
```

or, in your case this would probably work

```
arg<space>
```

Its not foolproof.  If there is punctuation directly after an instance of what you're looking for you would have to search for that explicitly, but for the most part it works pretty well.

Comment: Yeah, I do that occasionally, but as you say it's not foolproof.

Comment: This is such an important feature that I can't believe I'm still google-ing for answer in 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I was very surprised to see that there isn't a current addon that supports this.

If I needed to do it without an addon I would copy the text of a page into an editor and search for the regex

```
/\barg\b/i
```

Which will find

- arg!
- "arg"
- ARG
- ¿arg?
- arg-u-ment

but would not find

- argument
- barge

Comment: Hmm, good idea, though if I did copy it then I'd just use the "whole words" option in this case, which all my favourite editors have.

Comment: I love these crazy smart ideas! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [thread on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=269442) about this feature. There's a patch there that supposedly works, but you have to recompile Firefox yourself to install it, which I have not tried yet.

That particular thread is about the 18th duplicate of this bug. I read a good portion of one of the earlier ones, and the support staff were so dismissive of the idea that this might be useful to anyone that it was surreal.

I'll be using a different browser, myself.

Comment: This is a five year old question. That bug report is 11 years old. Are you sure this hasn't actually been implemented in that time?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Whole word search is not in Firefox at this point in time, which is why I ended up here. The bug report is eleven years old, and yes, they STILL haven't fixed it. That's not the first bug report either, it's a duplicate made years after the first one. When I posted this answer, the last comment on the bug thread was from the guy who wrote the patch, and it's from 12/31/2014.

Comment: To be clear, the reason they are not fixing it is not because they are lazy or incompetent. The Firefox team believe that the feature is *unnecessary* and that the extra checkbox would *clutter* the Find bar UI and confuse users. I’m not making this up.

Comment: @Timwi That belief is evidence of incompetence.

Comment: @DCShannon: Perhaps incompetence in UI design, yeah. I’m just saying it’s not like they couldn’t *code* the feature.